# Can I install binaries into the GAC via a VSIX installer?

Tags: installation, gac, binaries, vsix

I've got a hybrid installer which drops binaries on the target machine (WIX) as well as installs templates into Visual Studo (VSIX).  The VSIX is stored as a binary in the installer and is installed via a custom action when the installation is finalized.

It works, but there are a few issues.  I could get around those issues if I could skip WIX altogether and install everything via the VSIX.

The problem is that I have to drop some binaries in the GAC.  If I can drop a binary in the GAC in the VSIX, then everything would be cool.  But I can't seem to find any information on how to do this.

Alternatively, can I install binaries to a specific location on a target machine using VSIX?

Is any of this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. VSIX can't put files into the GAC and nor can it add registry entries for you. Exe or MSI install is what you'll need. Your users will lose the ability to enable/disable from within Extension Manager though, which is sad.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd393694(v=vs.100).aspx
 summarizes your deployment choices and confirms the no-GAC thing.

Comment: Gah.  Gotta be stuck with my Frankenstall and magic strings.  Sucks.